# User-defined class always returns 0

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple program, but I can't get this class to return the area of a rectangle; it always returns 0, including the class's variables.  For the life of me I can't get this darn thing to work.  Here's the main form:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim rect As New Rectangle
    'Dim strLength As String
    'Dim strWidth As String

    Double.TryParse(txtLength.Text, rect.Length)
    Double.TryParse(txtWidth.Text, rect.Width)

    'strLength = InputBox("Please input the length of the rectangle", "Calculate Area")
    'Double.TryParse(strLength, rect.Length)
    'strWidth = InputBox("Please input the width of the rectangle", "Calculate Area")
    'Double.TryParse(strWidth, rect.Width)

    lblArea.Text = rect.GetArea.ToString

End Sub
End Class
```

And here's the class

```
Public Class Rectangle
Private _dblLength As Double
Private _dblWidth As Double

Public Property Length As Double
    Get
        Return _dblLength
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If value > 0 Then
            _dblLength = value
        Else
            _dblLength = 0
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Width As Double
    Get
        Return _dblWidth
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If value > 0 Then
            _dblLength = value
        Else
            _dblLength = 0
        End If
    End Set
End Property

'when you call New in main form it initalizes the variables
Public Sub New()
    _dblLength = 0
    _dblWidth = 0
End Sub

Public Function GetArea() As Double
    Return _dblLength * _dblWidth
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error in your `Width` property: it's setting `_dblLength`, but returning `_dblWidth`.

`_dblWidth` will always be zero, so your calculated area will always be zero.